Can I hook into a systemd event for enabling or disabling a service?
Is it possible to tie into a service being enabled or disabled with systemd? I want my daemon to get an event when specific services are disabled or enabled with systemd.

If I understand correctly... yes...  I do a generalized /etc/systemd/system/administration.service which has an After = default.target to simply run commands I want to happen after system boot.
It has ExecStart = /root/scripts/administration.sh and in this text file I do various service <whatever> start or systemctl start whatever...  or  systemctl enable|disable whatever can be done as well.
Note

have #!/bin/bash at the beginning of the administration.sh (or equivalent ExecStart reference)
change that selinux context of the ExecStart= file to bin_t or something that will instruct selinux to let it execute;  I asked about this a while back best I came up with to choose was bin_t for my scenario.

semanage fcontext -a -t bin_t "/root/scripts(/.*)?"; restorecon -vR /root/scripts; ls -ldZ /root/scripts/*




After = default.target will trigger execution ater default.target state is hit. I want to trigger execution after a service is enabled or disabled: systemctl enable systemctl disable

I'm not sure if there's a clean elegant way to do that at that level, other than [off the top of my head] having a custom.service that runs a C code or bash script for example that polls systemctl list-unit-files to recognize when some specific service has changed between disabled and enabled.

Yes, polling for disabled and enabled jobs in list-unit-files would work, but that's not exactly an event-driven solution.
